# How can I copy <pre> tag code into clipboard in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I'm trying to copy the code written inside a `<pre>` tag into the clipboard.
How can I do that?
I have tried to solve this problem using the code below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<pre id="myInput">
  <span style="color:#97EDDC;">class </span>first
    {
        <span style="color:#97EDDC;">public</span> <span style="color:#97EDDC;">static </span> <span style="color:#97EDDC;">void </span> main(String args[]) // here S is capital of String word
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World!!"); // here S is capital of System word
        }
    }
</pre>
```

Give me the proper solution to copy code from pre tag into clipboard without including span tags.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately, `select()` can only be used on visible input elements. 
So what you can do is extract the text content of `pre` element.

Apply this to textarea and position the textarea outside the normal view area.

```js
function copyFunction() {
  const copyText = document.getElementById("myInput").textContent;
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.textContent = copyText;
  document.body.append(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', copyFunction);
```

```css
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<pre id="myInput">
<span style="color:#97EDDC;">class </span>first
{
    <span style="color:#97EDDC;">public</span> <span style="color:#97EDDC;">static </span> <span style="color:#97EDDC;">void </span> main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!"); 
    }
}
            </pre>

<button id="button">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Brilliant and Simple. I could suggest adding a latest line after `document.execCommand("copy");` :   `textArea.remove();` to remove it from your document…